# Disable auto renew for subscription on Android IAB

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I plan to use monthly subscription in my app, however I don't feel comfortable with auto renew process. My main concern is that users will not be aware that it's not a one time purchase, but a monthly auto renew subscription.

Is there a way on Google's In-app billing v3 or Google Play console to disable auto-renew for subscriptions? After all, next month I can show a purchase dialog for the user or at least have the auto-renew optional.

I haven't found anything on docs related to disable of autoRenewing.

Comment: If you don't want to auto-renew, don't use a subscription. Use a managed product, and consume it after one month.

Comment: Do you can find what you searched for ?